# How can I derive a control to an inherited form in VB.Net?

Tags: vb.net, forms, controls, windows-forms-designer, derived-class

everybody.
I have a VB form (named "MyBaseForm"), with an ImageList control ("MyIcons").
I want to derive MyBaseForm to another form ("MyDerivedForm"), allowing it to use MyIcons ImageList defined into the base class.
Of course what I want to do is to use the images of MyIcons to define MyDerivedForm with Designer and/or into the code.
To do that, i set MyBaseForm.MyIcons.Modifiers property to Protected (I also tried with Public and Protected Friend, with the same results...)

In this way, I expect that if i modify the MyIcons image list from the Designer view of MyBaseForm, I would find the change into MyDerivedForm.

But, if i for example add a new image to MyBaseForm.MyIcons, MyDerivedForm.MyIcons keeps being still unchanged.
It looks like when i create the derived form, VisualStudio just create a copy of the ImageList control. Which is not what i want.

To have MyDerivedForm.MyIcons updated, what I have to do is to manually remove the "MyIcons" section of file  MyDerivedForm.Designer.vb, so that, when I re-build, VisualStudio re-generates that section.

Is there a way to have that control REALLY derived, or, alternatively, to force the compiler to re-create MyDerivedForm.Designer.vb at any build (without having to manually manipulate the self-generated code)?

(I am using VB.Net 2005)

Comment: Does the same thing happen if you add it on an other form just to try it out?

Comment: "Visual inheritance" has plenty of traps, this is one of them.  Not a copy of the ImageList control, the derived form's .resx file isn't getting updated.  There is just no mechanism built into the IDE to take care of this.  Nor is it a simple thing to do, comparing images is quite tricky.  Only way to get ahead is to write code instead of relying on the designer, your base class can for example initialize a public List(Of Image) in its constructor.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, @HansPassant.
As you say the control is not copied: it looks it is inherited, in fact if i change an image in the base form, I find it changed in the derived one.
Instead the "hook" object are not correctly inherited - in fact they are created into the *.desginer.vb file. So, the trick is to delete the MyIcons section into the *.designer.vb file and rebuild. I just wish there was a setting to rebuild that file at any project rebuild.

Comment: @the_lotus, i am not sure i understood your suggestion...

Comment: Yes, @HansPassant, I also thought to write all the management of my icons in the code instead of using the designer. Kind of uncomfortable, but for sure more elegant...